# PHP CLI ODBC FreeTDS MSSQL Login failed

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds, unixodbc

I have an AW server with CentOS. I have installed PHP7.3 and the PHP-CLI for it. I also installed ODBC and FreeTDS modules to be able to connect to a MSSQL database.

I have written a PHP script which is connecting to this database with PDO.

When I call this script from the Browser with its URL, it works perfectly. I can connect to the database and use it.

But when I start the same script from the console using

PHP -f scriptname.php

it returns with

> SQLSTATE(42000) SQL Connect: 18456 [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'CorrectUserName'.[root@servername scriptname]

So at the moment I have no idea where to search for. Does anyone has an idea what is going wrong or what I can do to debug the problem?

Comment: I suggest looking at the logs on the SQL Server and finding the failed login error. That'll contain the *real* login error reason. If you then don't understand that error, [edit] said error into your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So I have to wait till the DB admin which is located in California is out of bed :)

Comment: Login errors are intentionally vague. If you can't tell us the *real* reason for the failure, we can only guess, and Stack Overflow isn't for guessing games I'm afraid.

Comment: Please also include the code you are using to connect. Is there potentially an environment variable being set by PHP on the browser view that isn’t included when calling it directly?